# Differential equations free fall application

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

A friend and I are having troubles setting up our differential equation for a free fall. The problem says this:

A body of a mass "m" falls from a certain height with a velocity "v". During the fall, the force due to air resistance is proportional to the square of the speed. Find the equation that represents its movement.

I think the differential equation should look like this:

$$m \frac{dv}{dt} = -mg + kv^2$$

But he thinks it should look like this:

$$mx'' - (x')^2 = 0$$

Which just does not make sense to me, since I don't think it would be a second order differential equation.

Comment: You are correct, your friend is not.  Just apply Newton's Law.  Though be sure to be consistent with your signs (which direction is positive, which negative).

Comment: Your friend should have $m \ddot{x} = -mg + k \dot{x}^2$. He is modeling the height, you are modeling the velocity.

Comment: I agree with you @copper.hat I want to check my signs now... I'm making the $$k(x')^2$$ positive and mg negative, since weight's going down and the air resistance is going in the opposite direction.

Comment: @ToñoBobadilla To be correct, it should be something like $-kv |v|$ as it always opposes the velocity. Here $v$ is negative. However most texts seem to implicitly assume that the sign of $v$ does not change.